# PHP Difference between Input::get() and $_GET[]

Tags: php, superglobals

What is the difference between

```
Input::get('value')
```

and this:

```
$_GET['value']
```

and when is better to use one of them?

Comment: Depends where `input::get()` is from - what framework are you using?

Comment: `::`  is the operator to call a method from a class,so search for `input` class and see how it uses the $_GET.It`s the same thing but the first method uses Object Oriented method

Comment: sidenote: FuelPHP also has [`Input::get()`](http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/input.html#/method_get)

Comment: @Ghost: I smell that all Codeigniter related frameworks will have a tendency to such named global (static class) functions. I found one in Laravel which perhaps is the most favourite amongst this branch of PHP frameworks.

Comment: @hakre i agree, now laravel is one of the favorites, but yeah they all basically do the same idea.

Comment: @Gaurav Dave: You can't just assign the laravel 5 tag as the OP didn't gave any hint which framework this is.

Comment: @hakre Input::get() is inside laravel, that's why I added

Comment: Yes, it's clear to me why you added it, I just think it's a bit too early to add. It is not only inside Laravel version 5 also inside other versions and frameworks. Unless the OP doesn't make this clear, you should not tag it that way IMHO. Also I think the question in the end isn't really framework specific. Perhaps motivated because stumbled upon in one framework but in the end could be generally answered (at least I tried).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input::get() is a function from Laravel

```
$email = Input::get('email');
```

> Note: The "get" method is used for all request types (GET, POST, PUT,
>   and DELETE), not just GET requests.

Retrieve all input from the input array:

```
$array = Input::get();
```

Retrieve all input including the $_FILES array:

```
$input = Input::all();
```

> And $_GET is superglobal variable in PHP used to get parameters from
>   querystring .

Comment: If you're going to include quotes, you should probably include a link to where the quote came from

Comment: basic difference yes, but you're including quotes, and if anyone wants to find further info around those quotes they now have to go and try and find where they came from

Comment: he is asking for "PHP Difference between Input::get() and $_GET[]", so please dont be oversmart... mind u r own business

Comment: If you ever wonder why your answer is at -1, and a reasonably similar answer is at +6 - come back to these comments.

Comment: thats fine, why dont you answer?

Answer (score 12):

The first line of code

```
input::get('value')
```

is some framework (perhaps [Laravel 4.2](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests)) wrapper around [PHP GET variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) like the second line of code

```
$_GET['value']
```

which is a [PHP superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) containing the same data but in plain vanilla PHP.

So the difference is more or less syntactical, e.g. how you prefix, write the name and the parenthesis:

```
Prefix    Name             Parenthesis

-none-    "input::get"        ()
 "$"      "_GET"              []
```

Next to syntactical differences, the first one is a function call while the other one reads a variable.

A function call allows to interact more, e.g. the framework can inject code to provide extra functionality in the "read" operation (returning/getting a value), like allowing to specify a default value if an input is not set, which plain vanilla PHP didn't support that well in the past (I think there will be an improvement on this in PHP 7 but can't find the RFC right now).

It's not that PHP can't deal with default values for non-existent GET variable entries, it's just some little boilerplate:

```
$value = isset($_GET['value']) ? $_GET['value'] : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

So apparently, `Input::get()` is from Laravel just like what @hakre said.

$_GET['value'] will parse the URL if there is a set value in it.

For example we have a url `http://www.example.com/index.php?myget=value`

we can use `$_GET['myget']` to fetch its value like so:

```
echo $_GET['myget'];
// this will print "value"
```

Comment: Input::get is a laravel function

Answer (score 1):

$_GET is PHP builtin variable.

It is global static variable and has several bad qualities, especially for testing. Laravel has introduced Input::get() instead so you can easily swap the implementation.

In Laravel there should be no reason to use $_GET and use Input::get() whenever possible.